# How to use pgadmin with Postgresql 15

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Postgres 15 with pgAdmin was installed in Windows 11 and new database was created.
Trying to connect to database in localhost throw error

> Request failed with status code 500

Postgres log  contains

```
2022-10-25 09:37:27.159 EEST [10508] ERROR:  UNION types "char" and text cannot be matched at character 745
2022-10-25 09:37:27.159 EEST [10508] STATEMENT:  
    SELECT cl.relkind, COALESCE(cin.nspname, cln.nspname) as nspname,
        COALESCE(ci.relname, cl.relname) as relname, cl.relname as indname
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_class cl
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace cln ON cl.relnamespace=cln.oid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index ind ON ind.indexrelid=cl.oid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class ci ON ind.indrelid=ci.oid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace cin ON ci.relnamespace=cin.oid
    WHERE cl.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_catalog.pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=16395::oid) AND cl.oid > 16383::oid
    UNION ALL SELECT 'n', null, nspname, null
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
        WHERE nsp.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_catalog.pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=16395::oid) AND nsp.oid > 16383::oid
    UNION ALL SELECT CASE WHEN typtype='d' THEN 'd' ELSE 'y' END, null, typname, null
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_type ty
        WHERE ty.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_catalog.pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=16395::oid) AND ty.oid > 16383::oid
    UNION ALL SELECT 'C', null, conname, null
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_conversion co
        WHERE co.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_catalog.pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=16395::oid) AND co.oid > 16383::oid
    UNION ALL SELECT CASE WHEN prorettype=2279 THEN 'T' ELSE 'p' END, null, proname, null
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc pr
        WHERE pr.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_catalog.pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=16395::oid) AND pr.oid > 16383::oid
    UNION ALL SELECT 'o', null, oprname || '('::text || COALESCE(tl.typname, ''::text) || CASE WHEN tl.oid IS NOT NULL
            AND tr.oid IS NOT NULL THEN ','::text END || COALESCE(tr.typname, ''::text) || ')'::text, null
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_operator op
        LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type tl ON tl.oid=op.oprleft
        LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type tr ON tr.oid=op.oprright
        WHERE op.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_catalog.pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=16395::oid) AND op.oid > 16383::oid
    ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

I installed  pgadmin4-6.15-x64.exe from pgadmin.org but problem persists.
Environment:

```
Version
6.15
Application Mode
Desktop
Current User
pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
NW.js Version
0.62.2
Browser
Chromium 99.0.4844.84
Operating System
Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
```

Comment: similar post: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAH-+qaYG=v0ts62XJqAjDJthJcvtc_EdMYv4Eh0ZnX3TM7Zm5A@mail.gmail.com 
so you need found which column have type "char"

Comment: can you try SELECT cl.relkind::text. works for me.

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin 4 6.17 has fixed this problem.